# Property annotated with @Value is always null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, null, telegram-bot

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {  

  @Value("${camel.component.telegram.authorization-token}") //properties
     private String botToken;  //null


            TelegramBot bot = TelegramBotAdapter.buildDebug(botToken);

  .
  .
  .
}
```

I don't understand why is not injected a param value defined in properties.

Comment: can you post the property file?

Comment: are you sure your component is being scanned by spring-boot? If the property didn't exist the @Value would fail.

Comment: There is no fallback there so, what @pcoates said, `Bot` is not a Spring Bean and the `@Value` annotation is not processed.

Comment: Is this line `TelegramBot bot = TelegramBotAdapter.buildDebug(botToken);
` in a separate method or in constructor of class `Bot`?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that @Value do not support relaxed binding, so check your property.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Component
    @PropertySource("file:${app_env_path}/${app_env}_DBconnection.properties")
    public class DBProperties {

        @Value("${driver.class.name}")
        private String driverClassName;

        @Value("${db.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${db.username}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${db.password}")
        private String password;

        @Value("${db.poolsize}")
        private String poolsize;

        //setters and getters  
    }


Property file - 
driver.class.name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.url=
db.username=
db.password=
db.poolsize=100
```

app_env_path = path where the location of the file
app_env = SIT/PROD